# Twisted and easy plugin development

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted

I'm creating this application, and I'm thinking of using Twisted for communication with users via XMPP(Jabber, chat protocol), with the possibility of using other means of communication in the future as well. My application is designed to support, or rather, rely on (independently developed) plugins. Most plugins will spend most of their time doing I/O. Ideally, all plugins would use Deferreds for all their I/O and return immediately(i.e. non-blocking), but I'm concerned that asking plugin-developers to do that is too much a burden, and will slow down and discourage plugin-development. Blocking high-level libraries are much more common(think Facebook or Twitter-libraries), and asking a possibly not-great coder to read up on Deferreds before developing a simple 10 loc Twitter-library doesn't sound like something I want to do.

The Twisted docs state that the maximum default size for the threadPool is 10, and that I should "be careful that you understand threads and their resource usage before drastically altering the thread pool sizes", which I don't think I do (understand), so giving each plugin a thread of its own doesn't seem like a good idea either.

Any suggestions?

Thank you for your help.

[EDIT] A standalone(non-server)-version of the application will also be available. Most plugin-developers will probably be using the standalone version. That's why I'm worried that developers will choose the easy way out, and create blocking plugins.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use threads.

The best example of how to make things easy for people not familiar with Twisted is the way [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org) defines [its plugin interfaces](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/topics/spiders.html).  You never look at a `reactor` or `Deferred` or anything - you just define what to do when certain pages are scraped, as callbacks.

Alternately, don't worry about it too much.  There are [plenty of independently developed](https://launchpad.net/tx) protocol support plugins that just use Twisted APIs directly; at the layer of implementing transport protocols, most people who can do it effectively have no problem learning Twisted.

Comment: Thank you for your response(and sorry for my late one!). It's not so much about developers not understanding Deferreds(although that's a valid point as well), but more about developers not being able to use most of the blocking, high-level networking-libraries. A developer that wishes to develop a Facebook-plugin cannot use any of the existing libraries(OAuth/Graph API), so they will most likely just create blocking plugins that only work on a standalone version, not on a server, and I want to avoid that.

Comment: It's better to just put pressure on the existing libraries to make event-driven versions.  First, it's not that hard; second, 99% of the implementation can be shared between blocking and event-driven versions, and third, the performance characteristics are better both for servers (which have to handle lots of connections) and clients (which have to handle user or network input at any time).  Also, from what I've found, library authors are surprisingly willing to accommodate their users, so try just asking for some OAuth or graph API libraries to add Twisted support!